# Connecting an HC05 bluetooth module to a Pololu A-Star 32U4 Prime SV microSD

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I am needing to connect an HC)% bluetooth module to a A-Star 32U4 Prime SV microSD and am unable to get it to work. For context I have a Pololu Dual G2 High-Power Motor Driver 24v18 Shield for Arduino attached to it.

The project is a bluetooth controlled tank robot. Am I missing a library or something?

I have connected the module to pins 0 and 1 as normal in an Arduino Uno and used the regular functions to try and get t working

```
#include "DualG2HighPowerMotorShield.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Create an instance of the motor shield class
DualG2HighPowerMotorShield24v18 md;

// Set up SoftwareSerial for Bluetooth on pins 7 (RX) and 6 (TX)
SoftwareSerial btSerial(0, 1);

char command; // To store the incoming command from the Bluetooth 
module

void stopIfFault()
{
  if (md.getM1Fault() || md.getM2Fault())
  {
    md.disableDrivers();
    while (1); // Halt execution if there's a fault
  }
}

void setup()
{
  btSerial.begin(9600); // Start the SoftwareSerial for Bluetooth 
communication
  md.init();
  md.calibrateCurrentOffsets();
  delay(10);
}

void loop()
{
  md.enableDrivers();
  delay(1);  

  // Check if data is available to read from the Bluetooth module
  if (btSerial.available()) {
    command = btSerial.read(); // Read the incoming byte

    switch(command) {
  case 'N': // Forward
    md.setM1Speed(255);  // Full speed forward for M1
    md.setM2Speed(255);  // Full speed forward for M2
    break;
  case 'S': // Backward
    md.setM1Speed(-255); // Full speed backward for M1
    md.setM2Speed(-255); // Full speed backward for M2
    break;
  case 'E': // Turn left
    md.setM1Speed(-255); // Full speed backward for M1
    md.setM2Speed(255);  // Full speed forward for M2
    break;
  case 'W': // Turn right
    md.setM1Speed(255);  // Full speed forward for M1
    md.setM2Speed(-255); // Full speed backward for M2
    break;
  case '0': // Stop
    md.setM1Speed(0);    // Stop M1
    md.setM2Speed(0);    // Stop M2
    break;
    }  
  }

  stopIfFault(); // Check for any faults

  md.disableDrivers(); // Put the MOSFET drivers into sleep mode.
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: How could anyone here know if you are missing a library?  You didn't post any of the code.  You say you used the pins for an UNO.  Is your board an UNO?

Comment: Soryr I have never used this platform before and thought I was being straight forward. The Microcontroller is a A-Star 32U4 Prime SV microSD which I have installed the library for, the motor shield is DualG2HighPowerMotorShield.h Which I have also installed the library for. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are atempting to use SoftwareSerial on pins 0 and 1.  Those are the pins for your normal serial port.  If you want to use 0 and 1 then you use normal Serial to communicate.  If you want to use SoftwareSerial so you can use the normal serial port for debugging, then you should choose different pins for the software serial instance.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and fingers crossed